# Size of a SQLite3 in memory database

Tags: sqlite, in-memory

I have a SQLite3 in memory database:

```
sqlite3* database;
sqlite3_open(":memory:", &database);
```

Is it possible to get the exact size of the database in memory?

I need to send the database to a client without saving it on a disk and have to tell him the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pragma page_count` (multiplied by `pragma page_size`).

Comment: That is not the exact size.
I want to cast the database object to a char* to send it, so i need the size of the object in byte, not the size of the data contained by the database.
`char* netData;
    netData = (char*) database;`

Comment: it has no chance to work at all. Take a look at `struct sqlite3` in sqlite sources: many members are pointers. How will you send a function pointer? A mutex pointer?

Comment: Hmm ok...
Is there a possibility to export all entries of the database at once to a char* and import it later into anotherone?

Comment: No, not without a temporal file (see sqlite_backup on how to copy entire db from memory to file). Theoretically, you can write an sqlite VFS backend for in-memory filesystem and use it for backup, but that's too much work.

Comment: Ok that´s bad...
So i have no other way as using a tmp file
Thanks for your advice

Comment: Does this take in consideration the space occupied by indexes too @AntonKovalenko? Edit: after tests it seems that yes. One-liner in Python: `print('size (MB):', next(db.execute('PRAGMA page_count;'))[0] * next(db.execute('PRAGMA page_size;'))[0] / 1024**2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlite3_memory_used() for this.

> The sqlite3_memory_used() routine returns the number of bytes of memory currently outstanding (malloced but not freed).

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/memory_highwater.html